# How to onmouseover swap image in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, onmouseover

I have this code in my wordpress template

```
<a onclick="get_project_data(<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>)"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $logoimg_id ); ?>" onmouseover="this.src=\'<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $logoimg_id+b ); ?>';" onmouseout="this.src=\'<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $logoimg_id ); ?>';"/></a>
```

But it doesn't work, I need to show a full colour image and a black and white with on over, the thing is that I need to do this automatically so I will upload to my server photo.jpg and photob.jpg (black and white) **css is not an option**.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not concatenating the strings correctly.

```
$logoimg_id+'b' (notice the quotes)
```

Secondly, you need to add the 'b' before the extension. You can do that by

```
$imgPath = wp_get_attachment_url( $logoimg_id );
$tmp = explode('.', $imgPath);
$tmp[0].='b';
$imgPath = implode('.',$tmp);
```

Another way would be to do a

```
echo str_replace('.jpg', 'b.jpg', wp_get_attachment_url( $logoimg_id ));
```

But I would not advise it

Answer (score 0):

You have escaped the single quote at the start of the 'this.src' definition but not at the end. the escaping is not required.
eg.

`onmouseover="this.src=\'<php 
echo wp_get_attachment_url($logoimg_id+b);?>';"`

should be:

`onmouseover="this.src='<php 
echo wp_get_attachment_url($logoimg_id+b);?>';"`